# fields except the id field is not getting imported using Django import export

Tags: django, django-import-export

These are my codes and csv file

```
class UserResource(ModelResource):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_member')
        import_id_fields = ('username',)


class UserAdmin(ImportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource


admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)

username, email, is_member, id
abc, abc@mail.com, True,
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you set:

```
fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_member')
```

you are restricting the fields you want to show from all to only the ones you declare.

The above statement means:

> import **only** these fields I'm telling you to import

But if you do:

```
fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_member', 'id')
```

I'm guessing you're going to get what you need

Comment: Sorry man, this doesn't make any difference, still it takes only username field

Comment: have you tried adding `export_order = fields` in your `UserResource`?